# How do i toggle click function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, touch, modernizr

I have following code

**html**

```
<a href="#" class="button">button</a>

<div class="holder">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <div class="content">
        <h3>hello there</h3>    
        <a href="#">view more</a>        
    <div/>    

</div>
```

**css**

```
.holder {
    margin-top: 130px;
    position: relative;
}
img {    
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
    z-index: 10;
}
.content {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
a {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.holder:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(90px);
}
.button {
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
   if (Modernizr.touch) {
    alert("touch support");
}

else {
     alert("no touch support");

    $('.button').toggle(
     function(){
             $('img').css({
              '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(90px)',
               '-moz-transform' : 'translateX(90px)'                 
             }); 
    },
    function(){
     $('img').css({
             '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(-90px)',
             '-moz-transform' : 'translateX(-90px)'                 

            }); 
    });
}
```

I am using modernizer to detect touch devices. In this code when the user hover on the image it reveal the `.content` class and i am trying to replicate it with jquery for touch devices since hover doesnt work well with touch devices.(In order To check the jquery code i have written the code to work with non-touch devices )

My questions are 1)Is this code correct and 2) the jquery code is written to change the position of image with click. Instead of that the button disappears.

This is what i have done with pure css --> [jsfiddle-css](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvraw/7/)

This is what i am trying to replicate with jquery which is not work --> [jsfiddle with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvraw/9/)

Comment: F.Y.I. The `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` event is deprecated.

Comment: @PalashMondal could you please help me to do this? :)

Comment: yup! done see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvraw/12/)

Comment: @PalashMondal Thanks a lot....just now notice that You have used migrate 1.1.0. i didnt know anything about it. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I have posted an answer so that you could know more about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a way:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    alert("touch support");
} else {
    alert("no touch ");
    var cssChanged = false; // remember wether the css has been changed
    // Note: I use true/false, but you could also use a counter, so you can make each Nth click do something
    $('.button').click(function(){
        if(cssChanged===false)
            $('img').css({
                 '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX(90px)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'translateX(90px)'                 
             });
            cssChanged = true; // remember css has been changed
        }
        else{
          $('img').css({
                 '-webkit-transform' : "",
                 '-moz-transform' :""                
             });
            cssChanged = false; // set var back to unchanged
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**F.Y.I. only**

For resolving your current [issue](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed), use the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin):

Using the plugin is easy; just include it immediately after the script tag for jQuery, for example.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

For more information, see the [jQuery Migrate documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvraw/12/)